# Drools Dynamic rule file generation from database (drl file) using Rule Template

Tags: java, drools

See below I have tried the example from the page below. Every things works fine  but I am not getting the rule applied, and generated status applicable from  this rule.

Location of sample code:
http://dilipsarangi.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/drools-610-dynamic-rules-in-database.html

I am able to load data from table in to the test case.
but when  `System.out.println(aa.getName() + "," + aa.getStatus());`

The `aa.getstatus` is null.

The dynamic generated rule .

```
package org.drools.template.jdbc;
dialect "mvel"

rule "ageRule_7"
    when
        $person : Person(age>=81 && age<100)
    then
     $person.status=":" + "Old Aged";
end

rule "ageRule_6"
    when
        $person : Person(age>=61 && age<81)
    then
     $person.status=":" + "Senior Citizen";
end

rule "ageRule_5"
    when
        $person : Person(age>=41 && age<61)
    then
     $person.status=":" + "Middle Aged";
end

rule "ageRule_4"
    when
        $person : Person(age>=18 && age<41)
    then
     $person.status=":" + "Youth";
end

rule "ageRule_3"
    when
        $person : Person(age>=13 && age<18)
    then
     $person.status=":" + "Juvenile";
end

rule "ageRule_2"
    when
        $person : Person(age>=6 && age<13)
    then
     $person.status=":" + "Young Age";
end

rule "ageRule_1"
    when
        $person : Person(age>=2 && age<6)
    then
     $person.status=":" + "Baby";
end

rule "ageRule_0"
    when
        $person : Person(age>=0 && age<2)
    then
     $person.status=":" + "Infant";
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the $person object in each rule, after amending the status property:

```
update($person);
```

Without doing this, any change to the object is not set in the working memory.

Although the above works, you are better using the modify keyword instead:

```
modify($person) {$person.setStatus=":" + "Infant"};
```

And similar for each of the rules. In this case the update keyword is not required.

There is some functionality such as property reactive beans where update cannot be used, so it is best to use modify as best-practice.

Comment: I am using 6.4.0 final 
The rule i posted is generated rule using the drt file.
Ther actual drt template 

'

I tried changing the Template with below changes it didnt work actually.
See the example in the link provide that actual drl file
'  then
  //   $person.status=":" + "@{status}";
     modify($person) {$person.status=":" + "@{status}";}'

Comment: Sorry, move the semi-colon outside of the { } brackets. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @JavaEvangelist It's also good practice to use `setX()` methods rather than access fields.

Comment: @Neil Belch,I am using Drools 6.1.0
     The change doesnt have any effect
         modify($person) {$person.status=":" + "Infant"};    

     I have my project in git hub 
     https://github.com/soasathish/Drools-dynamic-DB-Rule-set

Comment: @Neil Belch, I am using depreacted method , is that the cause of the problem

Comment: Yes possibly. You should use KieBase instead of KnowledgeBase, KieBuilder instead of KnowledgeBuilder and KieSession instead of StatefulKnowledgeSession (KieSession is stateful). The Knowledge..Factory classes no longer apply but instead there is a KieServices class which can be used to create new bases, sessions, etc - have a look at the API. I am not sure why the examples you have been given are using an older API and not the Drools 6 (KIE) one.

Comment: The JBoss.org Drools Documentation (http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html/, specifically Part II - KIE) is a good basis for how to create a rulesengine in Drools 6 and the various components (services, builder, container, etc) that you need to create.

Comment: There are changes in the interface in 6.5.0, but i am using the verion 6.1.0 with the sample code . **location of sample code http://dilipsarangi.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/drools-610-dynamic-rules-in-database.html**. I hope i am missing something

Comment: @Neil Belch ,@laune .if you know of any example . sample code to  implement this functionality Drools Dynamic rule file generation from database (drl file) using Rule Template
That willbe great

Comment: https://github.com/soasathish/Drools-dynamic-DB-Rule-set .   Could some one trey this code base and let me know wats the issue

Comment: @JavaEvangelist that repository is empty.

Comment: I have had a look at your code but don't know enough about .drt files to know if it is correct. The rule part of it looks ok although remove the $person.status line and use the proper setter (as laune advised).

Comment: The rulesengine code should be using Kie classes and not the older Knowledge ones. You are better reading the Drools 6 documentation as per my previous comment, and building one from there, or contact the owner of the code you have copied and discuss with them. To me it's not a small issue with the code, you need to use the latest API.

Comment: Hello, I am having the same issue. Could you please let me know what worked for you, if I can jog your memory? :)